# Problem with figure numbering (suspected \numberwithin hidden in a package)

Tags: numbering

I'm running into trouble with numbering figures - the actual figures have a caption with numbers that increment 1, 2, 3, etc. But the references to them within the text are using section numbers (2.1, 7.3, etc). A bit of googling suggests this is related to setting \numberwithin{figure}{section} somewhere, which I haven't done explicitly, so I'm guessing the offending command is lurking in a package I've called. I just don't know which one.

Can anyone identify the offending package please, and/or give an example of how to override this so that the figure numbers in the captions and the text are the same? Thank you in advance. I'm attaching a MWE below, which produces the labels 1 and 2 on the figures themselves, but references them as figures 2 and 3.1 respectively.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\title{Title of this}
\author{Me}
\date{\today}

\usepackage{pgf,pgfarrows,pgfnodes,pgfautomata,pgfheaps,pgfshade}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{colortbl}
% or whatever

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{txfonts}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{First section}
First section, with no figures to illustrate the point.

\section{Second section} 
Here is fig.~\ref{fig:AAA}

\begin{figure}[h!]\label{fig:AAA}
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{figure1.png}
  \caption{caption}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\section{Third section}
This is the third section

\subsection{A subsection}
Here is fig.~\ref{fig:BBB}

\begin{figure}[h!]\label{fig:BBB}
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{figure2.png}
  \caption{Another caption.}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{main}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A `\label` refers to the last stepped counter. Within a `{figure}` environment, it is the `\counter` macro which steps the counter. Long story short: `\label` *must*  come after `\caption`.

Comment: Unrelated: don't use the `center` env to center inside a float. Sounds counter intuitive, but here is the issue: the float, say `figure`, adds space above and below its contents so does the `center` env. Replace `\begin{center}` by `\centering` and remove `\end{center}`

Comment: unrelated but I would delete `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` and then save your file (as it is posted to this site) in UTF-8